# Creating only 1 instance or a Singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I used a class called 'City' & there will only be 1 city in the entire game; will it be beneficial to create an instance, if only 1 or a singleton.

The class itself will contain methods that won't all be static, & I've read that the singletons themselves consist of static attributes and methods only & can be bad practice or am I mistaken?

Comment: Share your code.. how many times are you going to call new and from which all places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton is a very common pattern and can help you to deal with just one instance of the object inside the entire runtime environment.
So don't warry to distinguish static and non-static methods... make all of them as non-static, because if will invoke them just by a `City.getInstance().method()` and you are sure that method() (and any other method) will be invoked just on the same instance.

Previous answer is correct, but you have to implement singleton in a different way if you are in a multi-thread environment (as a web application) and you need to be sure that just one instance will be created.

Infact, in the prevoius code it is possible that several concurrent threads will create a new City instance... Threads created later will use the last instance (because it overrides the first one in the static field).

There are several options to overpass this problem... the most common is the to make `synchronized` the `getInstance()` method:

```
public static synchronized City getInstance() {
```

A most efficient (in high-concurrent environment) is to use lazy initialization:

```
public class City {

    private static volatile City instance;

    public static City getInstance() {
        if( instance == null ) {
            synchronized (City.class) {
                if( instance == null ) {
                    instance = new City();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private City() {
      ... construct city here ....
    }

    // your City instance methods here (non-static)
    ....

}
```

Somewhere I see another implementation based on an initialization on the class just "on demand"...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a single instance and provide it as a method argument or as a constructor dependency in a place where you need to use it.

This way you could easily mock it out while testing other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are a very common pattern.

In java they are generated as a private instance of an object that cannot be created outside.

```
public class City {

    private static City SINGLETON;

    public static City get() {
        // lazy construction, may be required to synchronize....
        if( SINGLETON == null ) {
             SINGLETON = new City();
        }

        return SINGLETON;
    }

    private City() {
      ... construct city here ....
    }

    // your City instance methods here (non-static)
    ....

}
```

If you have a dependency injection framework in place, you can use this to manage the singleton instance for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best singleton mechanism available today is

```
public enum City {

   INSTANCE;

}
```

Then you refer to the instance like so

```
City.INSTANCE;
```

And if you need more methods in your city you do

```
public enum City {

   INSTANCE;

   private int xLoc;

   public int getX() {
     return xLoc;
   }
}
```

The single object with a "creation guard" technique is fallible.  While they have fixed JVMs so a race condition won't ensure that two instances are made (with one being garbage collected), none of these examples handle various other means of making duplicates of your instance.

For example, you could serialize your instance and then deserialize it and you'd have two copies.

Comment: Personally, I find singletons to be a code smell.  I'm pretty extreme in aligning with OO sometimes, and I have yet to find a situation where using a singleton couldn't be swapped out with a non-specially constructed class.  Yes, you might have to make accessing it explicit through the constructor or the methods, but _you want to do that_ because then you'll know what you are using by looking at the API and not the actual source code.